# Proving a summation inequality up to a value

Tags: calculus, summation

I have this summation inequality and am not sure how to reduce it:
$$\sum_{s=1}^{r+1} \frac{s}{N} \gt \sum_{s=r+1}^{N} \frac{s}{N}$$

We have that $r,s$ range from $1.....N$, where does this inequality change (to $\lt$) as $N \to \infty$? I know the value of $r$ should be $\frac{N}{\sqrt{2}}$ but I am not sure how to show this?

I first tried to use summation expansions but this gave me no luck:

$$\frac{r(r-1)}{2}\gt\frac{N(N+1)}{2}$$
$$N^2+N \lt r^2-r$$

However this leads me no closer and no root two in sight? Could anyone shed any light on this?

Thank you!

Comment: The inequality is equivalent to $(r+1)^2 > \frac{N(N+1)}2$.

Comment: @amsmath where did you get this from and how can I use this?

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that in the limit

$$\int_0^t x dx=\int_t^1 x dx \implies \frac12 t^2=\frac12 -\frac12 t^2\implies t=\frac{\sqrt 2}2$$

Comment: I don't understand how this helps (and why OP checked this answer).

Comment: @amsmath We are looking for the change in the inequality when $N\to \infty$ then we can look at the integral instead of the summation.

Comment: Uhh, I did not see the part with $N\to\infty$. My bad.

Comment: Also your way is fine, taking r/N we obtain indeed the result!

Answer (score 1):

You can mutiply everything by $N$, i.e.,
$$\sum_{s=1}^{r+1}s > \sum_{s=r+1}^Ns = \sum_{s=1}^Ns - \sum_{s=1}^rs.$$
This means
$$\frac{(r+1)(r+2)}{2} > \frac{N(N+1)}{2}-\frac{r(r+1)}{2}.$$
Multiplying by $2$ and rearranging gives $r^2+2r+1 > \frac{N(N+1)}{2}$, hence
$$
r > \frac{\sqrt{N(N+1)}}{\sqrt 2}-1.
$$